# How to set gradient color to the background of UILabel in iPhone

Tags: uilabel, cagradientlayer

I am using the following code to set the gradient color to the background of label but no effect what i am doing wrong?
Code is here:

```
    [self.teamName setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.teamName setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradientLayer.frame = self.teamName.bounds;
    gradientLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor], (id)[[UIColor blackColor]CGColor], nil];
    [self.teamName.layer insertSublayer:gradientLayer atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It working fine when i insert the CAGradientLayer to the main view.

```
[self.teamName setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.teamName setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradientLayer.frame = self.teamName.bounds;
    gradientLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor], (id)[[UIColor blackColor]CGColor], nil];
    [self.view.layer insertSublayer:gradientLayer atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 1):

So I was attempting to do this also! I finally made it work by just placing a UIView behind the label and changing the label background color to clear. I did this in a storyboard.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you did this exactly

Comment: So trying to do this on a UILabel presented its own problems. To circumvent this I just showed a standard UIView behind the UILabel and made the UILabel Background transparent so that you could see the gradient that you will more easily place in that uiview. For the placement of the views I believe I used a xib and just made references to them in code and used similar code like above @Nyakiba